# Example of an algorithm that lacks a proof of correctness

Tags: correctness-proof, hoare-logic

We have Hoare logic. Why is it still possible that an algorithm is right but there is no proof that it's correct? Suppose the algorithm is expressed in C. Then we can argue step by step that it's doing what it's supposed to do.

So my question is:

> Give me an example of an algorithm that's right but does not have a proof of correctness.

EDIT: I think a little background can help clarify where I'm going. Let me quote Scott Aaronson:

> Since the 1970s, there's been speculation that P $\ne$ NP might be independent (that is, neither provable nor disprovable) from the standard axiom systems for mathematics, such as Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory. To be clear, this would mean that either
>
> 1. a polynomial-time algorithm for NP-complete problems doesn't exist, but we can never prove it (at least not in our usual formal systems), or else
> 2. a polynomial-time algorithm for NP-complete problems *does* exist, but either we can never prove that it works, or we can never prove that it halts in polynomial time.

I'm referring to the second possibility. Since Aaronson can so confidently list it as a possibility, I think there must be an existing example of type 2. That's why I'm asking this question. But it seems a quick and clear answer is not in view.

Comment: What does it mean to say that an algorithm is correct if we don't have a proof of  correctness?

Comment: Do you mean "proof of correctness is impossible" or "nobody proved it to be correct"?

Comment: Algorithms don't have to be correct... suppose you have this: (1) put an empty bucket on the windowsill in the morning. (2) take it down in the evening. (3) measure the volume of water in the bucket. (4) repeat next morning. This is a description of an algorithm, but it doesn't describe anything that can be, without a stretch, called "correct". Interestingly, most programming code in the world is written in this particular way: it just isn't concerned with correctness of what it does at all.

Comment: @wvxvw I'm confused then, what does it mean for an algorithm to be "correct" then? If it does what it was intended to do, doesn't that mean it's correct? If the goal of your scenario was to find the average amount of water collected in the bucket during rainfall, for every day, wouldn't the algorithm be correct in that case?

Comment: @wvxvw Dijkstra would like to have a word with you. Jokes aside, I really hope that whoever writes the code which operates my car, planes, air traffic control, banks, medical equipment, nuclear power plants, and almost everything else that matters does not have that attitude regarding correctness. Correctness should be the first concern in programming (and for the vast majority of programmers, I think it is).

Comment: @chi you don't understand... it's not that programmers don't care for correctness of their code, it's that for some algorithms the concept of "correctness" is not applicable. Take some .NET WindowsForms application, which says something to the effect: "put this button with this label at this position, then put this other button at this other position and so on..." - there might be some interpretation of what this program does, under which what it does may be judged as (in)correct (eg. graphic designer says it "looks ugly"), but that's as far as it goes.

Comment: There are some factorisation algorithms that depend on the Riemann Hypothesis. Not sure if this counts.

Comment: The software that controls the lifts going to my office - can that be "correct"? What does "correct" mean? You can make an exact specification what the software should do, and the software may be proven to match the specification, but that's useless if the specification is no good.

Comment: I don't know what Hoare logic has to do with this, but would a potentially biased estimator (say, maximum likelihood) be an example of what you mean? It's "incorrect" because it's biased, but people use these all the time...

Comment: I've answered various questions on CS with algorithms that are correct but have no proof because I couldn't be bothered to prove correctness :-)

Comment: @wvxvw, well said. The only things that can be correct are __properties__ of algorithms, not algorithms themselves. There is only one class of programs I know where correctness is implicitly understood: Compilers. Given a programming language and a semantics, you may verify that the compiler _is correct_ (by which you mean of course that it preserves the semantics). But that's the only example I know of.

Comment: @chi `I really hope that whoever writes the code ... does not have that attitude regarding correctness.` _For the most part_, they do. Or they don't understand "provably correct software" nor "provably correct systems". (Search for those phrases.) It's far from trivial to create either if there is a significant degree of complexity. And there is, in your examples.

Answer (score 51):

Here is an algorithm for the identity function:

- Input: $n$
- Check if the $n$th binary string encodes a proof of $0 > 1$ in ZFC, and if so, output $n+1$
- Otherwise, output $n$

Most people suspect this algorithm computes the identity function, but we don't know, and we can't prove it in the commonly accepted framework for mathematics, [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory).

Comment: Are you sure *Check if the $n$th binary string encodes a proof of $0 > 1$ in ZFC* is an algorithm?

Comment: No, but the check can definitely be implemented algorithmically (i.e., by a Turing machine). In fact this is one of the requirements we have for proof systems - that proof validity be checkable algorithmically.

Comment: @Puppy ZFC proves $\lnot (0>1)$. But it could also prove $0>1$ if(f) it is inconsistent. Nearly everybody  believes ZFC is consistent, of course, but because of the incompleteness theorems we can't know that for sure.

Comment: I like this, but taken to its logical extreme it means that any algorithm would do as an example as long as the proof of its correctness relies on ZFC or an equivalent system. Which is to say, just about any algorithm that's ever been published. (The only exceptions would be algorithms whose correctness can be proven in a formal system that's too simple to express arithmetic.)

Comment: @Nathaniel Not at all. You can easily prove the correctness of every textbook algorithm, for example. This algorithm differs in that it relies on the *consistency* of ZFC, which is something that ZFC itself cannot prove.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus right, but the validity of any proof in ZFC is contingent on the consistency of ZFC, because an inconsistent system can prove anything.

Comment: @Nathaniel Personally, I believe in the consistency of ZFC. That's why I don't expect ZFC to be able to prove its own consistency.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Me too, but neither of us can prove it. (Except by using a more powerful formal system that is itself subject to the same argument.) If you believe in the consistency of ZFC then you believe in the correctness of your algorithm, and in fact you believe it exactly as strongly as you believe in the correctness of any other algorithm that's been proven correct using ZFC, no more and no less.

Comment: @Nathaniel Perhaps I believe it, but I cannot prove it. I also believe that P differs from NP, for example, but without a proof this belief isn't worth much.

Comment: @Nathaniel: If you like, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52935/discussion-between-user21820-and-nathaniel).

Answer (score 10):

Most algorithms have not been proven correct in Hoare logic. The main reason is that such correctness proofs are extremely expensive as of Jan 2017, probably by several orders of magnitude in comparison with 'mere' programming. There is a lot of ongoing work to reduce this cost by automation, but it's an uphill struggle.

Another reason why an algorithm might not have a correctness proof, and one that is more relevant in practise than the incompleteness phenomena that Yuval and chi mentioned, is that we might not know what this specification is. This problem has two dimensions.

- **The customers don't know what they want.** This is a well-known problem in software engineering, and software engineers have developed many approaches to deal with this.
- **The specification is difficult.** A good example is the correctness of cryptographic algorithms. Only recently [Micali & Goldwasser won Turing awards](http://www.acm.org/press-room/awards/turing-award-12) for specifying what cryptographic security means. Note however that that definition is (as far as I'm aware) for "theoretical cryptography" where you have a security parameter $n$ ranging over natural numbers, and adversaries are polynomial time probabilistic Turing machines. To the best of my knowledge (please correct me if I'm wrong) there is a mismatch between theory and practise, and concrete algorithms like AES and SHA256 are not quite within the purview of those theoretical specifications. I don't think there is full specification for such algorithms, hence we cannot, in principle verify them in the sense of e.g. Hoare logic.

Comment: AES is within the purview of definitions of cryptographic security.  (You do need to use concrete security definitions rather than asymptotic definitions, but you should be doing that anyway if you want security in practice.)

Comment: @D.W. Interesting. I was not aware of this. How is the asymptotic nature of theoretical cryptography circumvented? Can you please point me towards a paper on this? What about concrete cryptographic hash functions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_security, and the references listed there.  Hash functions are a more complex case, because it depends on what you use them for -- but the complexities are largely orthogonal to asymptotic security vs concrete security.

Comment: (Hash functions: If one-wayness suffices, then similar comments apply -- there are "concrete security" versions of the definitions that can be used in place of the asymptotic notions.  However, some protocols use stronger properties of hash functions that are harder to model.  The random oracle model is an (imperfect but useful) attempt to formalize that.  See https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2011/09/29/what-is-random-oracle-model-and-why-3/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle, http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/879/351.There are both asymptotic & concrete versions of the ROM.)

Comment: For encryption, you need two algorithms: One that encrypts, one that decrypts. One of them cannot be correct on its own. They can only be correct in a pair (you prove that decrypting an encrypted input produces the original). But for encryption, you want it to be uncrackable and that's something you cannot catch with "correctness".

Comment: @D.W. I have to disagree somewhat. While the papers by Rogaway and Bellare are great implying that they in any way allow for security proofs of primitives is misleading. Both of the papers are essentially about protocols (i.e. they assume primitives such as AES, SHA,RSA etc.) are secure and then prove things from there. The essential problem of proving the primitives themselves secure remains. If you have any references for proofs of primitives being secure I'd be interested. The second paper for example assumes RSA is hard which is very much an open problem.

Comment: While I generally agree with this answer, I've seen this argument used too many times to prove that program verification is useless, and correctness is irrelevant. What is typically omitted is that, while writing a full specification may be indeed hard, a _partial_ specification could be way easier -- and verifying that would still be very useful. For instance, a "no crashes" specification would surely not require a huge effort to write. A "no overflow" property would have prevented the 1996 Ariane 5 disaster, for instance.

Comment: @chi I certainly don't think program verification is useless, on the contrary. Indeed all my research is about program verification. I'm merely stating facts about the economics of program verification as of 2017. This [talk by Peter O'Hearn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcVx3g3SmmY) is instructive.

Comment: @chi The Ariane 5 accident was not a software accident. The programmers knew very well that an overflow  in the data coming from one of the sensors would lead to the destruction of the rocket. They decided not to handle the overflow because the *specification* said that sensor's data will never be in the dangerous range. The specification was wrong: it was reused from Ariane 4 which had a different sensor.  So no amount of program verification would have prevented this problem.

Comment: @chi The problem with partial specifications like "no crashes" is that if you want to establish even such a partial specifications you typically need a full specification (or nearly full specifications) of most parts of the program. For example: is the program if `shasum( "hello" ) == 9b29ad8fe0c97327d85aaafc3b03ea16519f887f then crash else 0` crash-free or not?

Comment: @DRF, I think you're responding to a claim I didn't make.  I didn't claim that concrete security allows a security proof of AES.  Rather, my claim is this: the answer's statement "Note however that [....] full specification for such algorithms" is not correct.  With concrete security, the definitions are not purely theoretical; they're not asymptotic; adversaries are not polynomial time TM's; AES *is* within the purview of the definitions; there *is* a full specification for AES.

Comment: I agree that proving a partial specification is still hard, in general (undecidable!), but it's not useless to state it and try to prove it. People working in static analysis did improve their techniques considerably (e.g. a part of the Airbus software was proved crash free, automatically, by the Astrée project in 2003). Sometimes, even in the industry, we _can_ prove software correct. While I don't want to underestimate the cost, software verification is getting undeserved negative publicity, which often throws away the baby with the water.

Answer (score 5):

This is tied to the incompleteness of the underlying logic. Indeed, Hoare logic usually contains a weakening or "pre-post" rule
$$
\dfrac{
P \implies P'
\qquad
\{P'\}c\{Q'\}
\qquad
Q' \implies Q'
}{
\{P\}c\{Q\}
}
$$
where the implications $P\implies P', Q\implies Q'$ need to be proved in an underlying logic, usually First-Order Logic (FOL) with some set-theoretic axiomatization like Zermelo-Fraenkel (ZF).

The tricky part is that we know such logic is incomplete, as proved by Gödel almost one century ago. More concretely, there is a predicate on natural numbers $P(n)$ for which we can prove inside the logic $P(0)$, $P(1)$, $P(2)$ and so on for any given natural constant, but there is no way to prove $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}.\ P(n)$.

From the computer science side, this weird behavior can be exemplified using computability theory. Suppose a Turing Machine $M$ when run on the empty tape does not halt in $n$ steps ($P(n)$). Then, in ZF we can prove such fact by essentially unraveling the execution step-by-step in the proof. However, when $M$ diverges, we can not hope to be able to prove divergence in ZF ($\forall n.\ P(n)$). Indeed, if this were possible for all given $M$, then we could semi-decide divergence by enumerating all the possible proofs for $\forall n.\ P(n)$, and halting when one is found. Since we know that divergence is not RE, this is impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Problem: Print "Yes" if every even number ≥ 4 is the sum of two primes, and "No" if there is an even number ≥ 4 that is not the sum of two primes.

Algorithm: Print "Yes"

Most people think that the algorithm is correct. There is no known proof, and it is quite possible that there *is* no proof.

Answer (score 3):

Any algorithm that is correct but we don't know how long it takes to run can be transformed into an algorithm that stops in a guaranteed amount of time but we aren't sure if it is correct.

For example, to find a prime larger than $n$, start counting up from $n+1$ testing if each number is prime until you find one.  Now modify it to give up and return $0$ if we can't find a prime after $\log(n)^2$ tries.  If the modified algorithm ever returns $0$, it is incorrect, but nobody knows if that ever happens or not.  Even with as many as $\sqrt{n}$ steps we can't prove a prime will always be found.

So, we have an algorithm that is correct but we have no proof that it runs in polynomial time, and an algorithm (the same one, but time-limited) that runs in polynomial time but we have no proof that it is correct.  And like with the $P=NP$ problem, for this example it is also plausible that no such proofs exist.